# How to compile html string appended with javascript to vue dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, datatables

I have a datatables component in my Vuejs app that uses ajax to load data and i want to add buttons to rows and the buttons should be able to call methods from my vue instance.

The button is in the form of a string like so

```
{name:'Action', render(a, b, row) {
    return `<a @click="showmore(${row.id})">View More</a>`;
}}
```

i've search every website for a solution and no one seems to have this same issue

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why write code as string and then parse it? Can't you prefer write smarts components with the features offered by the framework. For example you can dispatch an action dynamically if setting the action name a component prop. Or you can instantiate different kind of component by using the v-bind:is functionnallity

Comment: You can probably use some usage of v-html but that is NOT how you should be going about this. you should use `div(v-for="row in rows")` and then `<a @click="showmore(row.id)>View More</a>` will work perfectly fine (in your vue template, given that `data:{rows:[{id:'something1'},{id:'something2'}]}` be aware that if you need to set a new array element property value you need to use `Vue.set`

Comment: Hi Tony. As you may have gathered from the other comments, the reason you can't find a solution is that the approach you propose is wrong. You should define the buttons in your template, not append them via JavaScript. If you don't want the buttons to be visible until the ajax response is available, simply hide them with `v-if` or `v-show`.

Comment: thanks for your replies but look at it this way...
the part of the app where i want to add the string is part of another plugin that isn't connected to vue at all..

Comment: I'm using datatables.js to create tables and i'm trying to add buttons to the table rows...
so i can't exactly use v-if or v-show to hide or show it because the plugin will create the button from the string

Comment: Shameless plug, my component maybe of help with what you are doing: https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net#row-action-buttons

Comment: thanks @Noogen i'll use your plugin